# How to configure flume service on cloudera manager?

Tags: interceptor, flume, cloudera-manager

I am trying to configure a flume service in cloudera manager. I have a custom flume interceptor. Where should i place the custom built interceptor jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CDH 5.x
You can place the custom flume jar in

```
/var/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/phc/lib
```

The jar needs to be in all the flume nodes processing the data.